# Jsf - работа с фреймами

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf

Есть 4 таблицы, которые выводят записи из базы данных посредством JPA.
Должно одновременно показываться 4 таблицы, то есть на странице должно быть 4 фрейма, в каждый выводится отдельный файл. При переходе по отдельным ссылкам вверху, на странице должны увидеть отдельную таблицу. Как сделать шаблон этого файла?
[image: Вот как это должно быть]

Answer (score 1):

Данную задачу можно решить вообще без использования фреймов, если все страницы самодостаточны. Пример оформления страницы All Tables:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
<ui:include src="Table1.xhtml">
<ui:include src="Table3.xhtml">
<ui:include src="Table2.xhtml">
<ui:include src="Table4.xhtml">
</h:panelGrid>
```